# NESTJS download file from another back end API

Tags: nestjs

Trying to bring clarity to this issue. I need to get any attachment file from another back end and return in the nestjs controller.

Service code:

```
  getFile(token: string, orderId: number, fileName: string): Observable<any> {
      let url = `${this.configService.get<string>(
        'BACKEND_ORDER_BASE_URL',
      )}/file/download`;

      if (orderId) {
          url += `?serviceDistrictId=${orderId}`;
      }
      if (fileName) {
          url += `?fileName=${orderId}`;
      }

      return this.httpService.get(url, {headers:{Authorization: token
      }});     
   }
```

Controller code:

```
 @Get('download')
  @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  getFile(
    @Query('fileName') fileName: string,
    @Query('orderId') orderId: number,
    @AuthHeader() bearerToken: string,
    @Res() res: Response): Observable<any>
  {
          return this.fileService.getFile(bearerToken, orderId, fileName)
                                 .pipe(
                                         map(response => response.data.pipe(res))
                                );
   }
```

I get an error when running it: ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] response.data.pipe is not a function TypeError: response.data.pipe is not a function.

Can anybody help with the code solution that gets any file from another back end and returns it in nestjs controller?

Much Thanks

Comment: Here's the starting point from the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/streaming-files) in case you haven't seen it.

Comment: What is being returned from the httpService method? If you would type the response it would be much easier to work with.

Comment: http service will return file, attachments like pdf, word, outlook email.

Comment: Kenneth, I've seen the document but it has no use to me since it reads the file from the server disk, I need to path through that file from another http call.